# image upload works locally, but the deployed version on heroku crashes, paartial credentials messing

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, heroku, environment-variables

i have a python/django project deployed on heroku with aws s3 image upload, I can upload the image and post them on the website locally, but the deployed version on heroku is givinig me that error

PartialCredentialsError at /teams/1/add_photo
Partial credentials found in env, missing: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

I have the configuration file on my computer and it works locally with both aws_Secret_id & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
any help with that?!

Comment: Please try setting environment variable for  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as describe in docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: my AWS region is Ohio, I live in a near stated, do you think the region might be causing this

Comment: Region has no impact on connection thou.